# Measure theory proof verification. A specific property of sets with positive measure and the Lebesgue measure.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

I have a proof for the following question, could someone please verify it as i'm not confident whether its right.

> Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$, such that  $m(E)>0$, and $m(E^c)>0$ where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. Show that there exists an $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $r_n \rightarrow 0$ such that: $$\frac{1}{4}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{m([x-r_n,x+r_n]\cap E)}{2r_n}\leq \frac{3}{4}$$
>
> In proving this, we're allowed to use a stronger result: Besicovitcz theorem: $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}$ $$\frac{1}{4}\leq \liminf \frac{m([x-r,x+r]\cap E)}{2r} \leq \limsup \frac{m([x-r,x+r]\cap E)}{2r} \leq \frac{3}{4}$$

$Proof$

Following the hint by GEdgar:    Given an $x$ satisfying the stronger result you are allowed to use, choose a sequence $r_n→0$ so that you approach the $\limsup$.

Besicovitcz theorem gives us the required $x \in \mathbb{R}$. lets call $f(r)=\frac{m([x-r,x+r]\cap E}{2r}$, and lets call $A=\lim_{R \rightarrow 0} \sup_{0\leq r\leq R} f(r)$.

Now lets have a general sequence. We can let $r_1$ be anything so lets have $r_1=1$. Also, let $0\leq r_n \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.  Limsup always exists, so bu definition of a limit, if $0< R< \delta$, then $|\sup f(r) -A| < \frac{1}{2^n}$. Take $R< \min(\delta,\frac{1}{2^n})$ (to ensure that its bounded $\frac{1}{2^n}$. )

Then we start choosing $0<r_n< R$ such that $|f(r_n)-\sup_{0<r<R} f(r)|< \frac{1}{2^n}$. So then for $0<r_n< R< \min (\delta, \frac{1}{2^n})$, by the triangle inequality: $|f(r_n)-A|<\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$. So letting $n\rightarrow \infty$, we get that $f(r_n)\rightarrow A$.

Comment: Furthermore, how would one show existence of the $x$ without using the Bezikovich theorem?